# android admob top ad request when fullscreen ad is been dismissed

Tags: java, android, admob

I need to start **Top Ad** request when an **intersticial(fullscreen ad)** is been dismissed. Code crashes when setting adlistener for **Top Ad.** How could I solve it? Thank you.

```
Intersticial is requested on onCreate,
interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this, ID_for_my_App);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
interstitial.setAdListener(this);
```

When dismissed, **Top Ad** should be requested but crashes,

```
 @Override
      public void onDismissScreen(Ad ad) 
      {
        interstitial.setAdListener(null);
         adMob.setAdListener(this);
         AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
         adMob.loadAd(adRequest);
      }
```

Comment: post your entire activity and the crash stack trace. What is `adMob` a reference to in your onDismissScreen callback?